# application command in asp .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wanna write an in application command and i can run it via dotnet cli first i created my ICommand:

```
namespace new_stack.Commands;

public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

this is my helloWorld command that simply gets option and print it purpose f this command is testing:

```
using System;
using CommandLine;

namespace new_stack.Commands;
public class HelloWorldCommand : ICommand
{
    [Option('n', "name", Required = true, HelpText = "Your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {Name}!");
    }
}
```

and this is my registeration process in minimal program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommand, HelloWorldCommand>();

var app = builder.Build();

var commands = app.Services.GetServices<ICommand>();

Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, commands.Select(command => command.GetType()).ToArray())
    .WithParsed(type =>
    {
        var command = commands.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetType() == type);
        command?.Execute();
    });
```

when i want to run it with `dotnet run hello --name John` it errors that says

```
ERROR(S):
  Verb 'hello' is not recognized.

  --help       Display this help screen.

  --version    Display version information.
```

what is the problem exactly?